# "all columns must be set before insert" error on a ResultSet insert with UCanAccess

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I want to create an Access database connection using UCanAccess under Java 8. Here is my code:

```
String employeeName = endrollNameFields.getText();
String employeeAddress = endrollAddressFields.getText();        

try
{
    //------------CREATE CONNECTION TO DATA BASE--------------/

    String DBPAD = "sourceFolder\\employeeTable2.mdb";
    String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBPAD;                       


    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB, "", "");
    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String sql = "select * from employeeTable2";


    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);                  

    rs.moveToInsertRow();

    rs.updateString("Name", employeeName);
    rs.updateString("Address", employeeAddress);                        

    rs.insertRow();
    st.close();             

    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String sql1 = "select * from employeeTable2";
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>" + "<font color=\"#008000\">" + "<html><span style='font-size:1.5em'>Employee Successfuly Inserted to Data Base");

}
catch(Exception e1)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
}
```

I made entries to my JTextField but when i click the button containing codes above this error message appears:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Ucanaccess SQLException:invalid cursor state: all columns must be set before insert

What is missing or lacking in my code?

Comment: Does the table `employeeTable2` really contain only two rows? (name + address).

Comment: Why are you doing this through a result set, and not through an `insert` statement? As Stephan said, your table probably has more columns then the two you set. You need to set all columns when inserting through a result set.

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess uses HSQLDB as a "backing database", and HSQLDB requires that all columns in the insert row be given an explicit value before calling `.insertRow()`, including using `rs.updateNull("ColumnName")` to explicitly specify a NULL value. That's just the way it works.

This was discussed recently on SourceForge [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/a24fef50/#439c). The requirement may be lifted in a future version of UCanAccess.

### UPDATE

UCanAccess version 3.x, released in August 2015, has indeed removed the above requirement. Any columns not explicitly set in the insert row will contain the default value for the column (or NULL if the column is nullable and no default value is specified in the table definition).